# Excel 365, convert text to date

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

It looks like this has been a question for a lot of people, but I've read over a lot of posts and I still can't figure this out. I have a column of dates that I copied from a Wikipedia chart. Unfortunately it looks like they are in text format instead of date, but I can't figure out how to convert them to a date format. I think part of the issue is that some of the dates are ranges (Ex: May 29 - June 1, 1861), but even when I just work on a few dates that are not ranges (Ex: June 3, 1861), I can't get them to convert correctly.

Does anyone have suggestions on what I could/should do to convert these to a date format? I wasn't sure how to upload the excel file to this forum (and suggestions, I'll take!); here's a sample of the data.

[image]

Comment: Which Wikipedia page are you grabbing data from? Could you paste the link in your post?

Comment: You will not be able to convert those strings to Excel dates. Excel specifications for dates include the range from `1 Jan 1900` to `31 Dec 9999`.  So dates before `1/1/1900` can only be stored as text.

Comment: Hi all, thank you! Here is the link to the data:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_American_Civil_War_battles

Comment: It looks like removing the year from the text allowed the single dates (Ex: July 2) to convert from text to date. However, the date ranges (Ex: April 12-13) don't convert to dates. Would it be best to just eliminate the ranges and just put the final date?

Comment: If you remove the year from the date string, it is **NOT** being converted to a date in`1861` but rather to a date in `2020`.  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

As other users have mentioned, the bad news is you won't be able to store dates before 1900 as actual dates.

The good news is that you can use PowerQuery to do pretty much all of the work.

You can connect directly to the webpage and return the data from the table on the page (no copying and pasting). You would do that by using Data>Get & Transform Data>From Web, then pasting the URL of the Wikipedia page into the text box:

[image]

This will let you select the table on the page and pull it into PowerQuery, where you can apply as many steps as you want to prepare the data. Since some of this text parsing can get quite involved if you aren't familiar with the M language, I prepared a query for you. If you use Data>Get & Transform Data>Get Data>From Other Sources>Blank Query> and then, in the Power Query Editor, click on the Advanced Editor button on the Home tab, you can paste the following code:

```
let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_American_Civil_War_battles")),
    Data0 = Source{0}[Data],
    #"Change data types" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{"Date", type text}, {"Battle", type text}, {"State", type text}, {"CWSAC", type text}, {"Outcome Victory", type text}, {"Outcome Notes", type text}}),
    #"Filter out the headers" = Table.SelectRows(#"Change data types", each [Date] <> "Date"),
    #"Duplicate the Date column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Filter out the headers", "Date", "Date - Copy"),
    #"Split the date column on ""-""" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Duplicate the Date column", "Date - Copy", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("–", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Date - Copy.1", "Date - Copy.2"}),
    #"Trim the split date columns" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Split the date column on ""-""",{{"Date - Copy.2", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Date - Copy.1", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Convert the split date columns to text" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Trim the split date columns",{{"Date - Copy.1", type text}, {"Date - Copy.2", type text}}),
    #"Add Start Date Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Convert the split date columns to text", "Start date", each if not Text.Contains([#"Date - Copy.1"],",") then
[#"Date - Copy.1"] & ", " & Text.End([#"Date - Copy.2"],4) else [#"Date - Copy.1"]),
    #"Add End Date Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Start Date Column", "End date", each if [#"Date - Copy.2"] = null then [Start date] else
if Value.Is(Value.FromText(
    List.First(Text.Split([#"Date - Copy.2"]," "))), type text) 
then [#"Date - Copy.2"] else List.First(Text.Split([Start date]," ")) & " " & [#"Date - Copy.2"]),
    #"Remove the split date columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Add End Date Column",{"Date - Copy.1", "Date - Copy.2"}),
    #"Move the Start and End Dates to the beginning" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Remove the split date columns",{"Date", "Start date", "End date", "Battle", "State", "CWSAC", "Outcome Victory", "Outcome Notes"}),
    #"Add Start Year" = Table.AddColumn(#"Move the Start and End Dates to the beginning", "Start Year", each Number.FromText(Text.End([Start date],4))),
    #"Add End Year" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Start Year", "End Year", each Number.FromText(Text.End([End date],4))),
    #"Add Start Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add End Year", "Start Month", each Text.Split([Start date]," "){0}),
    #"Add End Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Start Month", "End Month", each Text.Split([End date]," "){0}),
    #"Add Start Day" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add End Month", "Start Day", each Number.FromText(Text.Replace(Text.Split([Start date]," "){1},",",""))),
    #"Add End Day" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Start Day", "End Day", each Number.FromText(Text.Replace(Text.Split([End date]," "){1},",",""))),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Add End Day",{"Date", "Start date", "Start Year", "Start Month", "Start Day", "End date", "End Year", "End Month", "End Day", "Battle", "State", "CWSAC", "Outcome Victory", "Outcome Notes"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

After you've pasted that into the Advanced Editor and closed the Advanced Editor, you should see something like this:

[image]

From here, I would encourage you to click the little gear icons next to each step in the query settings to see how the transformations are done (if you're interested in learning it, anyway!). You'll notice that I split the date ranges into Start Date and End Date. I made the assumption that if it wasn't a range, then the end date was the same as the beginning date (i.e. the battle was over in a day). I also split each of those into their component day, month and years, in case you wanted to filter on those items.

When you're ready, click 'Home>Close & Load' to put the query into your workbook.

Good luck!